# How to save instance state of fragment after using replace()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

My Activity has 3 child fragments - with only 1 showing at a time. I'm using a BottomNavigationView to switch between child fragments. The initial child fragment shown, GameFragment(), is inflated when the activity is created via `supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace()` which replaces the fragment container in my XML.

Firstly, let me show you the full lifecycle of me entering my activity, switching fragment on `replace()`, then switching back to the initial fragment on `replace()`. These log statements are only related to the Activity and Fragment A (fragment B & C not shown).

```
onCreate (Activity)
onAttach (Fragment A)
onCreate (Fragment A)
onCreateView (Fragment A)
onActivityCreated (Fragment A)
```

`.replace()` Fragment A with Fragment B

```
onPause (Fragment A)
onStop (Fragment A)
```

`.replace()` Fragment B with Fragment A

```
onAttach (Fragment A)
onCreate (Fragment A)
onCreateView (Fragment A)
onActivityCreated (Fragment A)
```

In order to retain my fragment state when switching fragments using `replace()`, I've tried the following methods which have both failed.

1. Changing the value of a member variable in the fragment in `onDestroyView()` and then accessing it in `onActivityCreated()`
2. Adding to `getArguments()` in `onDestroyView()`and accessing in `onActivityCreated()`.

   ```
   class GameFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

       var truthisvisible = "string"

       override fun onDestroyView() {
           super.onDestroyView()
           truthisvisible = "stringafter"
           arguments?.putString("success", "success")

       override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false)
       }

       override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           Log.d("truthisvisible", truthisvisible) // prints "string"
           if (savedInstanceState != null){
               Log.d("LifecycleChange", "onActivityCreated savedInstanceState") // savedInstanceState is always null
           }
           super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
           Log.d("truthisvisible", truthisvisible) // prints "string"
           val print = arguments?.getString("success", "failure")
           Log.d("bool", "..." + print) // prints "...null"
   ```

I've also tried changing the variable `truthisvisible` in `onPause()`, as well as trying to receive the variable in `onCreateView()` however the variable never changes to `stringafter`. Same goes for `getArguments()` - the arguments don't change.

Also, the `savedInstanceState` in all these methods are `null`. Though I expect this as `onSaveInstanceState()` is never fired when replacing fragments.

I'm totally at a dead end here. How do I change or save a variable in my fragment when `replace()` is called? Here's my parent activity if you're curious:

```
var initialFragmentLoad = false

class TruthOrDare : FragmentActivity(), BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (!initialFragmentLoad){
            return true
        }
        val selectedFragment = when (item.itemId){
            R.id.action_leaderboards -> LeaderboardsFragment()
            R.id.action_options -> OptionsFragment()
            else -> GameFragment()
        }
        Log.d("ChosenFragment", selectedFragment.toString())
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_layout, selectedFragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
        return true
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_truth_or_dare)
        bottomNav_truthordare.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        bottomNav_truthordare.selectedItemId = R.id.action_game
        initialFragmentLoad = true
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return
        }
        val firstFragment = GameFragment()
        firstFragment.arguments = intent.extras
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_layout, firstFragment).commit();
    }

}
```

I would also like to know *why* I can't change the variables using my above methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a handler class

```
public static class GameHandler {
  public static string truthisvisible;
}
```

and then just call

```
Gamehandler.truthisvisible = "stringafter";
val previousValue = Gamehandler.truthisvisible;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try stopping your fragment from re-inflating it's view in `onCreateView()` like this

```
 if (view != null) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    parent.removeView(view);
 } else {
    //here you put your current code from `onCreateView()`
 }
```

Comment: Does `view` refer to `getView()` here? I've added my onCreateView in my code now - I'm not sure how your code fits with my function: https://i.imgur.com/C1EJKja.png

Comment: In your code `View view = inflater.inflate()...`, then `return view`;